# Como capturar hardware id

Tags: c

Estou tentando encontrar uma forma de capturar o serial do HD, CPU e placa mãe, o CPU eu encontrei um modo que é usando o cpuid.h, agora a placa mãe e o HD eu não encontrei maneira de poder capturar, alguém tem alguma ideia ?

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas maneiras de fazer isso. Você pode usar o comando `system` em `c` para chamar diretamente um comando do terminal.

### For Linux:

```
system("hdparm -i /dev/hda | grep -i serial");
```

#### Sem usar system:

```
static struct hd_driveid hd;
int fd;

if ((fd = open("/dev/hda", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK)) < 0) {
    printf("ERROR opening /dev/hda\n");
    exit(1);
}

if (!ioctl(fd, HDIO_GET_IDENTITY, &hd)) {
    printf("%.20s\n", hd.serial_no);
} else if (errno == -ENOMSG) {
    printf("No serial number available\n");
} else {
    perror("ERROR: HDIO_GET_IDENTITY");
    exit(1);
}
```

### Para Windows:

```
system("wmic path win32_physicalmedia get SerialNumber");
```

#### Sem usar system (Baseado em [Getting WMI Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ):

```
hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
    bstr_t("WQL"),
    bstr_t("SELECT SerialNumber FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia"),
    WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
    NULL,
    &pEnumerator);
hr = pclsObj->Get(L"SerialNumber", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
```

Solução retirada do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049367/how-do-i-get-the-disk-drive-serial-number-in-c-c).

Comment: Curti a resposta, mas não está completa - a autora da pergunta quer saber também sobre o serial da placa mãe. Você só escrever "maneiras de fazer 'isso'" sem deixar explicito (em português :-)  )  que o 'isso' é obter o serial do HD.

Comment: @jsbueno Eu estava esperando um comentário da autora da pergunta para saber se isso é suficiente. De repente ela está trabalhando no MacOSX e nenhuma das informações que eu dei seriam suficientes ;-)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta GabrielOshiro, então o que pretendo fazer é que seja possível trabalhar em todas as plataformas. Eu tenho um programa já pronto, o que eu quero fazer é salvar o serial id do HD, da cpu e placa mãe no banco de dados, de cada um conectado ao meu programa, pois os bloqueios vão ser feitos através de tais informações

Comment: @carolzinha Mas quando vc compila um código em C vc sabe qual a plataforma para a qual você está compilando. Mesmo que você queira fazer um código único que rode em várias plataformas vc vai ter que compilar o seu programa para cada plataforma, correto? Se esse for o caso, você tem a informação do sistema em tempo de compilação. E você tem que usar `system` para chamar comandos do console que te dêem essas informações. Em algum lugar do seu programa vc tem que ter um `if` que selecione qual plataforma você está.

Comment: @GabrielOshiro Eu queria uma forma que não precise chamar comando no terminal, por que o objetivo é capturar o serial id assim que conectarem em meu servidor e salvar o mesmo no mysql.

Comment: @carolzinha Mas o código em c estará rodando no cliente, correto?